# return name of the array that contains certain key with jq

Tags: jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "somekey": "somevalue",
  "blue_services": [
    "service-a",
    "service-b",
    "service-c"
  ],
  "otherkey": "othervalue",
  "red_services": [
    "service-d",
    "service-e",
    "service-f"
  ],
  "black_services": [
    "service-g",
    "service-h",
    "service-i"
  ]
}
```

I want `jq` to return the name of the array that contains certain value:

for example:

if I look for `service-a` jq should return `blue_services`
if I look for `service-h` jq should return `black_services`

I manage to extract the arrays that match certain regexp with:

```
keys[] | select(test ("[aA-zZ]_services"))
```

But i dont know how to then search inside for a match and return the relevant name, I have also tried piping to contains/has/any

ideally I would like to use a variable to be able to do several searches for service-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `to_entries` to get an array of key-value pairs. Search the values using `IN`, and output the key. Use `--arg` to import a string from the command-line.

```bash
jq -r --arg q "service-a" 'to_entries[] | select(IN($q; .value[]?)).key'
```

```
blue_services
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uEZorg5A35S)

Comment: I get `jq: error (at <stdin>:268): Cannot index string with string "value"` while trying with a real world JSON (output from jsonnet), if I add `.[] |`at the beginning ti seems to be able to read it but then it says that `string("somethingInMyJson")` has no keys.

Comment: @AlexanderMeise I'm afraid I can't help you if you don't disclose the differences of your real world data to the samples you provided. Maybe you first need to traverse the real world data down to the snippet from the sample. What about your own approach from the question (using regexp)? Does it behave the same using the sample and the real world data?

Comment: It is  just more fields with "key": "some.value", other arrays that contain objetcs, and then even more arrays with nested arrays, just a more complex JSON in general, I guess a solution would be to process only the arrays that are named: `"[aA-zZ]_services"` and ignore the rest of the JSON (that can be deep nested or have "strange characters") what I mean is: it's a valid JSON, its shouldnt make a difference if the rest of the file is more/less complex I understand..

Comment: @AlexanderMeise "a more complex JSON" is the key. Regardless whether you pre-filter keys by a regexp, or just try and discard using `?` from my approach, you need to first get to the right level within your "complex JSON". You could, of course, dive in recursively using `..` or `walk`, but unless your target items are really scattered randomly within your structure, this shouldn't be your first choice. Maybe try step-by-step reducing your real-world data towards the sample (or the other way round), and see which step makes it work (or break), so you can report the structural difference here.

Comment: My arrays are in the level explained in the example, in fact, the beginning of the JSON is exactly as shown in the example. Then, the rest of the file contains nested arrays and so on, but my arrays are "in the first level". Thanks for your help Ill try it out.

Comment: @AlexanderMeise Regarding "Then, the rest of the file contains nested arrays". Are these nested arrays under yet another key **within** the top-level object (just like `.otherkey` or `.black_services` in the sample), or do they come **after** the first object, making your input a stream of (different) single JSON items. For the first case, I don't see a problem with any of the approaches, for the latter, try prepending your filter with `input | ` and use the `-n` flag, to disregard any other inputs. Here's an altered [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dY7Bj-g8uyN).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it by *streaming* the input.  `select` passes only arrays having `$q` (your variable input) as an element, and then `.[0][-2]` extracts the key name for the array.

```
jq --stream -r --arg q "service-a" 'select((.[0][-1] | numbers) and (.[1] == $q)) | .[0][-2]'
```

Adapted demo on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/3SLSMMoVIcd).

Answer (score 1):

You have two good answers to your specific question already. I have a more generalized answer for how to search JSON without having to rewrite your query every time the JSON structure changes: a script called [jqg](https://github.com/NorthboundTrain/jqg/) that can, among other things, execute PCRE-compatible searches within the JSON printing out the results. Using your example JSON:

```
$ jqg service-h /tmp/example.json
{
  "black_services.1": "service-h"
}
```

By default, the script will flatten the JSON, search both keys and values for the given string, and output the results. There are many options to control both the searching and the results; this invocation will search only values for the string (`-v`), and output the original, unflattened JSON (`-t unflatten`):

```
$ jqg -t unflatten -v service-h /tmp/example.json
{
  "black_services": [
    null,
    "service-h"
  ]
}
```

Sparse arrays are a little wonky, as you can see. With the unflattened JSON, though, you can dump that back into `jq` to manipulate it as you like, e.g. pull out just the top level key:

```
$ jqg -t unflatten -v service-h /tmp/example.json | jq -r '. | keys[]'
black_services
```

That simple manipulation can be done in `jqg` itself, though (`jqu` automatically unflattens the results, `-K` says to output just the keys in the results, and `-r` works just like it does in `jq`):

```
$ jqu -rKv service-h /tmp/example.json
black_services
```

Where it shines is when the json structure changes, especially when the structure is arbitrarily complex. Using this (randomly generated) JSON:

```
{
  "dicta": 299,
  "erat": "mentitum proin putent",
  "tale": {
    "appareat": "dignissim",
    "dictas": "signiferumque netus mundi offendit",
    "quando": [
      "mazim torquent similique",
      "autem",
      237
    ],
    "proin": {
      "iudicabit": true,
      "copiosae": "fabulas non nec brute",
      "antiopam": -111,
      "montes": "consequuntur torquatos dictas nusquam"
    }
  }
}
```

I can easily execute PCRE-compatible searches:

```
$ jqg 'dictas|proin' /tmp/complex.json
{
  "erat": "mentitum proin putent",
  "tale.dictas": "signiferumque netus mundi offendit",
  "tale.proin.iudicabit": true,
  "tale.proin.copiosae": "fabulas non nec brute",
  "tale.proin.antiopam": -111,
  "tale.proin.montes": "consequuntur torquatos dictas nusquam"
}
```

with unflattened results:

```
$ jqu 'dictas|proin' /tmp/complex.json
{
  "erat": "mentitum proin putent",
  "tale": {
    "dictas": "signiferumque netus mundi offendit",
    "proin": {
      "iudicabit": true,
      "copiosae": "fabulas non nec brute",
      "antiopam": -111,
      "montes": "consequuntur torquatos dictas nusquam"
    }
  }
}
```

searching just the values:

```
$ jqu -v 'dictas|proin' /tmp/complex.json
{
  "erat": "mentitum proin putent",
  "tale": {
    "proin": {
      "montes": "consequuntur torquatos dictas nusquam"
    }
  }
}
```

printing out just the raw top level keys:

```
$ jqu -rKv 'dictas|proin' /tmp/complex.json
erat
tale
```

So, the same basic `jqg` invocation run on both radically different JSON structures produces the same, desired output:

```
$ jqu -rKv service-h /tmp/example.json
black_services

$ jqu -rKv 'dictas|proin' /tmp/complex.json
erat
tale
```

Note: I am the author of `jqg`